# Exponential number formatter - javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, logarithm, exponent

I was looking for a good way to format exponential values that satisfies all of the following...

- Works in HTML `<canvas>` elements
- Has a configurable base value (i.e. `10`, `2`, [`e`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)))
- Shows the exponent as superscript not just `9x10^3`
- Handles negative superscript exponents

The easy solution I found was to use some npm package like [`numeral.js`](http://numeraljs.com/), and just do something like...

```
const n = 9000;
const label = numeral(n).format('0[.]00e+0') // 9e+3
```

Which not terrible for base 10 but when using base `2` or `e` it isn't great

```
numeral(Math.pow(2, 4)).format('0,0e+0') // 2e+1
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "using base 2 or e"? The example you give still only uses `e+0`. What's the result you would like to see? Also, what are you trying to tell us with that table? It looks good to me.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I was looking to answer this myself (see below) to provide a better formatter for values of any base value. The `e+0` value assumes base 10 which doesn't nicely format base `2`, `e` or others. See the table in my answer below. The table above was to illustrate the current format when using `numeral.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own function that I think is a huge improvement from the `numeral.js` exponential formatter.

```
const superscriptMap: Record<string, string> = {
  0: '⁰',
  1: '¹',
  2: '²',
  3: '³',
  4: '⁴',
  5: '⁵',
  6: '⁶',
  7: '⁷',
  8: '⁸',
  9: '⁹',
};

const getSuperScriptNumber = (n: number) =>
  `${n > 0 ? '' : '⁻'}${Math.abs(n)
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .map((c) => superStringMap[c])
    .join('')}`;

const logFormatter = (n: number, base: number = 10) => {
  // Number.EPSILON to help with rounding errors
  const sign = n < 0 ? '-' : '';
  const nAbs = Math.abs(n);
  const exp = Math.log(nAbs) / Math.log(logBaseMap[base]) + Number.EPSILON;
  const roundedExp = Math.floor(exp);
  const constant = numeral(nAbs / Math.pow(logBaseMap[base], roundedExp)).format('0[.]00');
  const baseLabel = base === LogBase.Natural ? 'e' : logBaseMap[base];
  const expString = getSuperScriptNumber(roundedExp);
  return `${sign}${constant} x ${baseLabel}${expString}`;
};
```

Using this function I summarized a few example formatted values below.

| Base (base) | Exponent (exp) | `Math.pow(base, exp)` | `numeral(n).format('0[.]00e+0')` | `logFormatter(n, base)` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | -5 | 0.000009999999999999999 | 10e-6 | 1 x 10⁻⁵ |
| 10 | -2.445 | 0.0035892193464500534 | 3.59e-3 | 3.59 x 10⁻³ |
| 10 | -1 | 0.1 | 1e-1 | 1 x 10⁻¹ |
| 10 | 0 | 1 | 1e+0 | 1 x 10⁻⁰ |
| 10 | 1 | 10 | 1e+1 | 1 x 10¹ |
| 10 | 2.545 | 350.75187395256796 | 3.51e+2 | 3.51 x 10² |
| 10 | 5 | 100000 | 1e+5 | 1 x 10⁵ |
| 2 | -5 | 0.03125 | 3.13e-2 | 1 x 2⁻⁵ |
| 2 | -2.445 | 0.18364607915978864 | 1.84e-1 | 1.47 x 2⁻³ |
| 2 | -1 | 0.5 | 5e-1 | 1 x 2⁻¹ |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1e+0 | 1 x 2⁻⁰ |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2e+0 | 1 x 2¹ |
| 2 | 2.545 | 5.836081376960701 | 5.84e+0 | 1.46 x 2² |
| 2 | 5 | 32 | 3.20e+1 | 1 x 2⁵ |
| `Math.E` | -5 | 0.006737946999085469 | 6.74e-3 | 1 x e⁻⁵ |
| `Math.E` | -2.445 | 0.08672613490173116 | 8.67e-2 | 1.74 x e⁻³ |
| `Math.E` | -1 | 0.36787944117144233 | 3.68e-1 | 1 x e⁻¹ |
| `Math.E` | 0 | 1 | 1e+0 | 1 x e⁻⁰ |
| `Math.E` | 1 | 2.718281828459045 | 2.72e+0 | 1 x e¹ |
| `Math.E` | 2.545 | 12.743228086065521 | 1.27e+1 | 1.72 x e² |
| `Math.E` | 5 | 148.41315910257657 | 1.48e+2 | 1 x e⁵ |

> I hope this helps someone that is in my position. Please edit this port or let me know if there is a calculation error.